# Table wont load into WPDB

Tags: wpdb

Hi im trying to add a table into my WPDB and its still redirecting to an older table (that i have deleted) despite me using the same name it shows this error

```
WordPress database error: [Table 'bitnami_wordpress.questions' doesn't exist]
SELECT * from questions ORDER BY id DESC
```

this is my attempt to insert a table in the WPDB

```
//Insert the Table in WPDB
function insert_demo_table_into_db(){
  global $wpdb;
  // set the default character set and collation for the table
  $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
  // Check that the table does not already exist before continuing
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{$wpdb->base_prefix}questions (
  id bigint(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  short_question bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  long_question bigint(20),
  possible_answer varchar(100),
  comment varchar(100),
  multi varchar(100),
  multiNum varchar(100),
  uniq_name varchar(100),
  Created varchar(100),
  Status varchar(100),
  assigned varchar(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES wp_posts(ID)
  ) $charset_collate;";
  require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
  dbDelta( $sql );
  $is_error = empty( $wpdb->last_error );
  return $is_error;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? Is the table not getting recreated? Where are you querying it from?

Comment: from the original WPDB no its not getting created at all

Comment: Heve you reviewed the documentation? I can see that you haven't followed at least one of these requirements: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dbdelta/#comment-1329

Comment: I think you're missing a backtick... At CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS the table name has an opening backtick but no closing one.

Comment: This error means that the table doesn't have been created at all
`WordPress database error: [Table 'bitnami_wordpress.questions' doesn't exist]` when you select the table. So according to this error, this has nothing to do with your question.
`Hi im trying to add a table into my WPDB and its still redirecting to an older table (that i have deleted) despite me using the same name it shows this error` Maybe rephrase or update your question...